# How can i set a default integer value for entry box in tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a countdown timer that takes hours, mins, and seconds from the user. I wish to set 0 as the initial condition. here's the code for the entry box I used

```
# entry box for hour
self.hour = IntVar()
self.time_hour= tkinter.Entry(font=("Helvetica", 10))
self.time_hour.grid(row=3,column=0, columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=110)
```

I've tried using self.hour.set(0) but it was not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have forgotten to add `self.hour` as value to your Entry.

Try

```py
# entry box for hour
self.hour = IntVar()
self.time_hour= tkinter.Entry(font=("Helvetica", 10), textvariable=self.hour)
```

`IntVar` has 0 as default value: you don't need to do anything for it.